# Is it possible to get photos stored on the iPhone without PHAsset?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, photos, phasset

Is it possible to get the photos stored on the iPhone without use PHAsset ?

It's because the use of PHAsset forces me to use this method :

```
PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset( ... )
```

And this method takes times to be executed.

I just want to get the images directly from the folder where they're stored.

Comment: Probably a violation of the API/SDK EULA.

Comment: How much time does it take, and how much time would it take if you could load the image as a file? Reading several MB of data usually takes more than 1 millisecond.

Comment: To get the photo, the execution of the method I typed in my first post takes too much time.

I want the photos taken by the camera.

Comment: How much is "too much time"? 1 hour, 1 sec, 1 usec?

Comment: It's more 1 second, because I want to made a View like the Photos app view on the iPhone, the view when we swipe right or left to see photos.

And the view which I developed has a jolt when the user swipe between photos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to access these files directly as they are out of the Sandbox auf your application.
What takes time, when you use the method

```
PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset( ... )
```

is that the file gets loaded into memory and decoded into an UIImage.
To avoid this please have a look at the method

```
PHImageManager.defaultManager(). requestImageDataForAsset( ... )
```

This method loads the file as NSData.

Note: If you want to build a Photo application, where users can swipe between photos, the best strategy may be the following.

1. Preload the images the user is likely to load (e.g. one photo before and after the current displayed one)
   using `PHCachingImageManager`
2. When the user swiped to the actual image use

   PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset( ... )

As the image are preloaded, this should be much quicker

Another approach would be to first load smaller thumbnail images and then with a delay load the fullscreen image.